# can't connect to test ds azure provisioning url

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I created in laravel a scim route with total return results 0 and I got the secret certificate in application registration and generate certificates and secrets but it doesn't work.

SystemForCrossDomainIdentityManagementCredentialValidationUnavailable Details: We received this unexpected response from your application: An HTTP/404 Not Found response was returned rather than the expected HTTP/200 OK response. To address this issue, ensure that the tenant URL is correct. The tenant URL is usually in a format like: https://<>/scim. If this does not resolve the issue, contact the application developer to ensure their SCIM endpoint conforms with the protocol

as is returning my route:

```
return response()->json(['schemas'=>["urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:ListResponse"],'totalResults' => 0, "Resources" => [],"startIndex" => 1,"itemsPerPage" => 20]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The AAD provisioning service starts off by sending a few GET requests looking for non-existent resources - i.e.: GET /Users?userName eq "469787bf-b179-4ef9-bc60-ee07cc78fd47". The expected response is a 200/OK with ListResponse type response with totalResults of 0.

The message you're getting back indicates that one of these test API calls is getting a 404 rather than a 200. This could be because the URL is incorrect, or the SCIM implementation is noncompliant and is returning a 404 for a query that returns zero results.